# Connecting mongodb atlas through mongoengine in django after hosting on EC2 apache2

Tags: python-3.x, django, ubuntu, mod-wsgi, mongoengine

I am trying to host django project on EC2 usnig apache2 which is using mongodb atlas as database.

When I am running this locally on EC2 after openning some port like 8000, it runs properly but on apache it's giving error.

Below is some TLSFeature error, I am facing

```
mod_wsgi (pid=67994, process='tracky', application='ip-IP_ADDRESS|'): Loading Python script file '/home/tracky/tracky-api/tracky/wsgi.py'.
mongodb+srv://username:password@host/dbname?retryWrites=true&w=majority

mod_wsgi (pid=67994): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/tracky/tracky-api/tracky/wsgi.py'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tracky/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 1278, in _get_socket
    sock_info = self.sockets.popleft()
IndexError: pop from an empty deque

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tracky/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tracky/lib/python3.6/site-  File "/home/tracky/tracky-api/trackyapi/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .views import Tracky
  File "/home/tracky/tracky-api/trackyapi/views.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .serializers import GoalsSerializer, GoalSerializer
  File "/home/tracky/tracky-api/trackyapi/serializers.py", line 9, in <module>
    class GoalSerializer(DocumentSerializer):
  File "/home/tracky/tracky-api/trackyapi/serializers.py", line 11, in GoalSerializer
    uid = ReferenceField(User, write_only=True)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tracky/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework_mongoengine/fields.py", line 217, in __init__
    self.queryset = model.objects
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tracky/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset/manager.py", line 38, in __get__
    queryset = queryset_class(owner, owner._get_collection())
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tracky/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mongoengine/document.py", line 215, in _get_collection
    db = cls._get_db()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tracky/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mongoengine/document.py", line 193, in _get_db
    return get_db(cls._meta.get("db_alias", DEFAULT_CONNECTION_NAME))
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tracky/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mongoengine/connection.py", line 363, in get_db
    db.authenticate(
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tracky/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 1492, in authenticate
    self.client._cache_credentials(
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tracky/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 780, in _cache_credentials
    with server.get_socket(all_credentials) as sock_info:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tracky/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 1231, in get_socket
    sock_info = self._get_socket(all_credentials)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tracky/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 1281, in _get_socket
    sock_info = self.connect(all_credentials)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tracky/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 1180, in connect
    sock = _configured_socket(self.address, self.opts)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tracky/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 1002, in _configured_socket
    sock = ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=host)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tracky/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/pyopenssl_context.py", line 313, in wrap_socket
    ssl_conn.do_handshake()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tracky/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/pyopenssl_context.py", line 116, in do_handshake
    return self._call(super(_sslConn, self).do_handshake, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tracky/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/pyopenssl_context.py", line 107, in _call
    return call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1915, in do_handshake
    self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1618, in _raise_ssl_error
    self._context._ocsp_helper.raise_if_problem()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 294, in raise_if_problem
    raise self._problems.pop(0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 590, in wrapper
    valid = callback(conn, ocsp_data, data)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tracky/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/ocsp_support.py", line 292, in _ocsp_callback
    ext = _get_extension(cert, _TLSFeature)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tracky/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/ocsp_support.py", line 119, in _get_extension
    return cert.extensions.get_extension_for_class(klass)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tracky/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cryptography/x509/extensions.py", line 134, in get_extension_for_class
    raise ExtensionNotFound(
cryptography.x509.extensions.ExtensionNotFound: No <class 'cryptography.x509.extensions.TLSFeature'> extension was found
```

Any suggestion will be helpful.
Thanks.